# RecyclerView Adapter methods are not being called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I know this question has been posed a hundred times, which only makes it more frustrating for me.

I basically took this code from Camera2Basic in https://github.com/android/camera-samples.

Here's what I've built on top from that project so far:

```xml
<!-- selector_fragment.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/camera_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
class SelectorFragment : Fragment() {
    private var binding: SelectorFragmentBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = SelectorFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding!!.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val cameraManager =
                requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val configList = enumerateCameras(cameraManager)
        val layoutId = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
        val genericAdapter = GenericListAdapter(configList, itemLayoutId = layoutId) { innerView, item, _ ->
            innerView.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = item.title
            innerView.setOnClickListener {
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                        .navigate(SelectorFragmentDirections.actionSelectorToCamera(
                                item.cameraId, item.format))
            }
        }
        val cameraList: RecyclerView = binding!!.cameraList
        cameraList.adapter = genericAdapter
        val items = cameraList.adapter!!.itemCount
        cameraList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    ...
}
```

```kotlin
/** Type helper used for the callback triggered once our view has been bound */
typealias BindCallback<T> = (view: View, data: T, position: Int) -> Unit

/** List adapter for generic types, intended used for small-medium lists of data */
class GenericListAdapter<T>(
        private val dataset: List<T>,
        private val itemLayoutId: Int? = null,
        private val itemViewFactory: (() -> View)? = null,
        private val onBind: BindCallback<T>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GenericListAdapter.GenericListViewHolder>() {

    class GenericListViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = GenericListViewHolder(when {
        itemViewFactory != null -> itemViewFactory.invoke()
        itemLayoutId != null -> {
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(itemLayoutId, parent, false)
        }
        else -> {
            throw IllegalStateException(
                    "Either the layout ID or the view factory need to be non-null")
        }
    })

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GenericListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position < 0 || position > dataset.size) return
        onBind(holder.view, dataset[position], position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

When I go into the debugger, none of the Adapter methods are being called.
However, when I turn the screen the Adapter is called, and the app starts behaving as expected.

The problem also occurs when I use the old bindings -- i.e. `view.camera_list.adapter = genericAdapter`.

There shouldn't be any async happening, and `enumerateCameras` (omitted for brevity) returns as expected. Calling `adapter.getItemCount` directly returns as expected.

Adding the `cameraList.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method seems to have no effect.

I've tried removing `app:layoutManager` and setting `cameraList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())` directly; in fact, I've tried both with the same results.

Changing to a FrameLayout from ConstraintLayout makes no difference.

I've updated all my `androidx` dependencies and all other relevant dependencies.

Again, turning the device and triggering a relayout causes the list to populate as expected. I'm not sure what mechanism is calling adapter methods.

I'm going to try to roll my own Adapter in the mean time instead of using this one.

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: it seems `configList` is empty when fragment first created

Comment: @GuanHongHuang yes, but it's not being updated after I call `notifyDataSetChanged`, and I don't see where that's a requirement. Most tutorials and resources seem to do something similar, unless I'm missing something

Comment: It could be because`enumerateCameras` is defined as static method inside companion object, `configList` is still not populated during first instance of fragment creation?

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni I'm not sure what the difference would be. However, I went ahead and changed it so that it's just `val configList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, and the result is the same. It even shows the list of numbers correctly when I rotate it.

Comment: Refresh `RecyclerView` only when `configList` is not empty, add logs and see when exactly the data is available.

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni in lieu of logs, I've been using the debugger, and the data is available statically when `onViewCreated` is called. Also using the debugger, I've gleaned that none of the Adapter methods are being called after `notifyDataSetChanged` or, as they are in many tutorials and resources, being called implicitly after `onViewCreated`/`setLayoutManager` finishes. Since you asked, though, logging also confirms this.

Comment: I have been working on `camera2` Video sample myself. I made all the changes as you did. It works pretty well in my case. I am attaching the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VjJ6.png) as is,

Comment: I think it's a problem with the navigation components or something. I added a dummy text view, and now it looks like it's not showing the layout at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my navigation components. It was a combination of my misunderstanding, shotgun coding, and missing a simple detail. The default NavController/NavHostFragment depends on an ActionBar, which was not present in the theme I had chosen for a previous test, `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

I was totally off-base calling out the RecyclerView/Adapter, since the layout wasn't going to the screen at all. After setting up the NavBar to work according to the navigation components tutorial, the output is as expected.